# MySQL workbench to PHPMyAdmin: 0000-00-00 00:00:00 - Invalid default value

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

Why do I get an error message when I import SQL created MySQL workbench?

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;

SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';





-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- Table `$type`

-- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `type` (

  `type_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,

  `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,

  `created_on` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ,

  `updated_on` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`type_id`) )

ENGINE = MyISAM

AUTO_INCREMENT = 1

DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;



SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;

SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

error message,

```
#1067 - Invalid default value for 'created_on'
```

What is wrong with this value - `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: Try changing it from `timestamp` to `datetime`.

Comment: Tried it but same problem... :-(

Comment: could be a problem in phpmyadmin itself?

Comment: Not sure...  timestamp, and datetime both accept '0000-00-00 00:00:00' as a default construct.

Comment: sorry. it now works. I should not have set the default value in DATETIME.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: missing a word in my reply -  I should not have set the default value as `NULL` in the column of DATETIME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DATETIME instead of TIMESTAMP

Comment: got it - it now works with ``created_on` DATETIME NOT NULL ,`

Comment: Im not quite sure how timestamp is working in mysql, but I also have this problem all the time, so I'm using timestamp default current_timestamp on one field and on other datetime with 0000-00-00 00:00:00. The answer should be somwere here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html but i'm too lazy to find it :p

Comment: See the answer below, by @saaj.

Answer (score 11):

Shortly, the answer by `wormhit` is wrong. Notice 3rd line:

`SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';`

`TRADITIONAL` according to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_traditional) is a shortcut that expands to

`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, STRICT_ALL_TABLES, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER`

So by specifying the mode you actually prohibiting zero dates. In *MySQL Workbench 6* go *Preferences -> Model: MySQL* and remove `TRADITIONAL` from *SQL_MODE to be used in generated scripts*.

Also notice that `TIMESTAMP` is timezone-aware type, whereas `DATETIME` is not. So depending on timezone settings of machine, *MySQL*'s global and session settings result-sets could vary.

Comment: If I were you, I'd remove the reference to the other user's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the other methods mentioned here don't work, you can try this:
Modify `my.ini` of the mysql path.

`sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"`

Comment: if not denfine sql-mode, l think the answer of saaj can work